# The Button wont show and The Shape keep Disappearing when create new one

Tags: java, swing

Thank you I finally got the button to work properly but now I'm stuck at  making the shape I just create to stay on screen. Every time I click to create new shape I select the other shape I just create disappear. I look at custom paint but still confuse

```
public class ShapeStamps extends JFrame {

    Random numGen = new Random();
    public int x;
    public int y;
    private JPanel mousePanel, Bpanel;
    private JButton circle, square, rectangle, oval;
    private int choice = 0;

    public ShapeStamps() {

        super("Shape Stamps");
        Bpanel = new JPanel();
        circle = new JButton("Circle");           
        square = new JButton("Square");           
        rectangle = new JButton("Rectangle");
        oval = new JButton("Oval");

        circle.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                choice = 1;
            }
        });
        square.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                choice = 2;
            }
        });
        rectangle.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                choice = 3;
            }
        });
        oval.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                choice = 4;
            }
        });
        mousePanel = new JPanel();
        mousePanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        MouseHandler handler = new MouseHandler();
        setVisible(true);
        addMouseListener(handler);
        addMouseMotionListener(handler);
        add(mousePanel);
        Bpanel.add(circle);
        Bpanel.add(square);
        Bpanel.add(rectangle);
        Bpanel.add(oval);

        add(Bpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setSize(500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter implements
            MouseMotionListener {

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            x = e.getX();
            y = e.getY();

            repaint();
        }
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponents(g);

        setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        if (choice == 0) {
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 32));
            g2d.drawString("Shape Stamper!", 150, 220);
            g2d.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 16));
            g2d.drawString("Programmed by: None", 150, 245);
        }
        if (choice == 1) {

            Color randomColor1 = new Color(numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256));
            g2d.setPaint(randomColor1);
            g2d.drawOval(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100);
        }
        if (choice == 2) {

            Color randomColor2 = new Color(numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256));
            g2d.setPaint(randomColor2);

            g2d.drawRect(x - 50, y - 50, 100, 100);
        }
        if (choice == 3) {
            Color randomColor2 = new Color(numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256));
            g2d.setPaint(randomColor2);
            g2d.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double(x - 75, y - 50, 150, 100));
        }
        if (choice == 4) {
            Color randomColor2 = new Color(numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256), numGen.nextInt(256));
            g2d.setPaint(randomColor2);
            g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(x - 50, y - 25, 100, 50));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly when posting, this will help others help you.

Comment: Don't use a null layout and setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Read the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information. Fix your code and if you still have problems then post the updated code that is formatted properly. Also, `don't override paint()`. There is also a section in the tutorial on `Custom Painting` that gives an example of the proper way to do painting.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime the JFrame gets repainted it will go through the drawing process, somif you stamp something on the screen you would have to have a data structure to hold the "objects" that were stamped. This way, each time the drawing process gets called it will repaint the objects on their correct position (and maybe colors with you decide to change this too)